# does a database containing list of all journals and related meta-data exist?

Tags: journals, open-access, databases

Is there any database where I can find a list of all the journals and filter the database based on the Impact factor, publisher and category (Open access or commercial)?

Comment: What is the purpose of that? I mean, you get some info about some journals. That's it. Nothing about their fitness for your article. Everyone has this lists of journals everywhere on Google. Not very accurate list, but because journals do not share free information from everyone. And they profit from bibliometrics too.

Answer (score 1):

Since *"the impact factor"* is a product of Clarivate (formerly Thomson Reuters) the only databases that include the impact factors of all included journals are the ones of Clarivate, i.e. [Web of Science (WoS)](http://webofknowledge.com/wos). To get access to the databases a licence is required. Maybe your library has licenced the databases. But be aware of the fact that WoS only includes selected journals. If a journal is not in WoS, it officially does not have an impact factor.